# C# HttpClient HTTPs TLS Data Included

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, .net-5

I have a few ipv4 address which I am attempting to screen scrape on.  I have a basic program written in C# .Net 5.0 which uses HttpClient to make the GET request with a web server.  My client works perfectly for a while until the rate limit happens. (Predictable).  Which, I then presume I can change my IPv4 address (through Outbound NAT) and it should work in theory.  However it doesn't.  I get the same error.

I have confirmed that the outbound IPV4 switches correctly. I wrote a small script in C# with https://www.ipify.org/ to get my outbound Ipv4.

I have tried to make this connection in Google Chrome after the rate limit, it works fine.  I tried to make the query in Postman on the same machine, it works fine.

Its almost like C# has some type of certificate it uses, and the server is banning the certificate. However I think I nulled this by trying to run my agent on multiple machines.

What type of data is seen in the TLS handshake that could yield this type of detection?

I notice that C# normally uses TLS 1.1 or 1.2, however Google Chrome uses 1.3. But I think I tested this theory too by disabling TLS 1.3 in Postman, and it works. I also tried to run in very old Internet Explorer, and it works.

Also, I did copy all the params/body and headers into the C# application to mimic fully. I also tried to curl the request, it works too.

**Please understand this question is less about the code and more about the principal.** To my understand of a curl request the only thing that is noticeable on the first request is the TLS process followed by the actual requests/headers/body. Even if an answer is not provided, pointing to the direct and me learning is completely acceptable.

Code Subset :

```
            HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate
            };
            if (proxy != null)
                handler.Proxy = proxy;
            var client = new HttpClient(handler);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authority", "awebsite.itsawebsite.com");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.9");
            //More Headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36");
            var response = client.GetAsync("https://secure.website.com").Result;
            var stringResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: I doubt this has anything to do with TLS.  A more likely culprit is rejecting the .Net User Agent string.

Comment: Or he keeps disposing his `HttpClient` until he runs out of sockets. With no code, no error message, how could we know?

Comment: @DourHighArch Excellent point.

Comment: SO is really wrong place to ask general "how to defeat rate limiting" - we can help with concrete errors/problems  but figuring out for you why some service blocks your scraper (which is most likely also against the TOS) is not something SO is set to help with... (Ignoring legal and moral consequences of such activity).

Comment: [You're using HttpClient wrong and it is destabilizing your software](https://josef.codes/you-are-probably-still-using-httpclient-wrong-and-it-is-destabilizing-your-software/)

Comment: Use a proxy inspector like Telerik Fiddler tool to see the actual requests you are sending out and inspect the payload (if any if you POST / PUT) and headers you are sending out... You can decrpyt the SSL traffic with it also if needed... This seems like an issue with the user-agent possibly. This is not up to the HttpClient itself but how it is used probably (or the misues of async await with `.Result` here) but to the server side handling the rate limiting. Try changing the UA header and other headers you are sending like accept-language.

Comment: This is not about port exhaustion or reuse of sockets.  I have ensured this is not an issue. I understand using .Result is not good. That is not the issue.

@VedranMandić Yes, I have played around with sending some, different ones, and none at all.  All which work when I initially start. However after sometime of using just >1< IP address, the other IP address receive a limit.  I really think the key here is the fact that TLS 1.2 (Which is what .Net sends) is blocked but 1.3 TLS is not. Its almost like the public key being sent in the TLS handshake is somehow being tracked and monitored.